# Сделать три горизонтальних меню по центру (вертикально и горизонтально)

Tags: html, css

Всем привет. Нужно сделать три горизонтальних меню по центру div блока
Как на [рисунке](https://ibb.co/H23jKN0).

[image]

Так же переместить знаки наверх.
Вировнять по горизонтали смог, как вертикально уже пару дней не получается.

Вот мой [код](https://jsfiddle.net/7b0rpnfm) html и css.

```css
body {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

.container {
    background: #ffd1f7;
    height: 60%;
    width: 80%;
    outline: 10px double black;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

div.container div {
    display: inline-block;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

li {
    font-size: 20px;
    float: left;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-right: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}

ul.menuFirst li {
    background: url("../images/checked.png") no-repeat;
    padding-left: 30px;
}

ul.menuFirst li:hover {
    background: url("../images/checked-hover.png") no-repeat;
}

ul.menuThird{
    list-style-image: url("../images/smile.png");
}

ul.menuThird li:hover {
    list-style-image: url("../images/smile-hover.png");
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div>
        <ul class="menuFirst">
            <li>About</li>
            <li>News</li>
            <li>Teachers</li>
            <li>Programs</li>
            <li>Cost</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
        <ul class="menuThird">
            <li>About</li>
            <li>News</li>
            <li>Teachers</li>
            <li>Programs</li>
            <li>Cost</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

в div контейнере должно быть 3 листа

```
<div>
    <ul class="menuSecond">
        <li>About</li>
        <li>News</li>
        <li>Teachers</li>
        <li>Programs</li>
        <li>Cost</li>
    </ul>                                                               
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот этот блок, свёрстанный на флексах:

```css
body {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    background: #ffd1f7;
    outline: 10px double black;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

li {
    font-size: 20px;
    float: left;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-right: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}

section {
    height: 100%;
}

section:first-child {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

section:first-child ul {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

section:last-child {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

section:last-child ul {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
            <section>
                <div class="first">
                    <ul>
                        <li>About</li>
                        <li>News</li>
                        <li>Teachers</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="second">
                    <ul>
                        <li>About</li>
                        <li>News</li>
                        <li>Teachers</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="third">
                    <ul>
                        <li>About</li>
                        <li>News</li>
                        <li>Teachers</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </section>

            <section>
                <div class="first">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Programs</li>
                        <li>Cost</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="second">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Programs</li>
                        <li>Cost</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="third">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Programs</li>
                        <li>Cost</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
```

Думаю, принцип понятен

Comment: да, спасибо. а как передвинуть маркера списка слева наверх? есть какие-то варианты?

Comment: никак, можно создать "псевдо" маркер с помощью псевдоэлементов.